# Java JDBI Handle to convert "TINYINT" and "BIT" datatypes to Boolean values throws NullPointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

Converting TINYINT and BIT values in the MySQL database to BOOLEAN using JDBI handle but unable to convert these two fields and it returns a null pointer.

Below is the setup -

**Column info in MYSQL for is_hdfs_mapping and is_active :**

```
name : is_hdfs_mapping
type: BIT
length: 1
possible values: [0,1]

name : is_active
type: TINYINT
length: 1
possible values: [0,1]
```

**SQL query for fetching the data from MySQL database:**

```
private static final String QUERY_BILLING_RATE = "select * from billing_rate_mappings where customer_id in (:param1) and is_hdfs_mapping = (:param2);";

private static final String QUERY_ACTIVE_BILLING_RATE = "select * from billing_rate_mappings where customer_id in (:param1) and is_active = (:param2);";
```

**JDBI handle usage in msxBillingMasterDAO.java**
This jdbi handle is a generic handle for fetching my data from MySQL.

```
public <T> List<T> findAllByParams(String query, Map<String, Object> map, Class<T> type) {
    List<T> records = jdbi.withHandle(handle ->
                handle.createQuery(query)
                        .bindMap(map)
                        .mapToBean(BillingRateMapping.class)
                        .list());
    return records;
}
```

**Target object**

```
public class BillingRateMapping {
    private Boolean isHdfsMapping;
    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

**Exception thrown while trying to convert to Boolean using JDBI handle -**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.reflect.BeanMapper.specialize(BeanMapper.java:148)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultSetResultIterator.<init>(ResultSetResultIterator.java:38)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.lambda$of$0(ResultIterable.java:53)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.stream(ResultIterable.java:141)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.collect(ResultIterable.java:197)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.list(ResultIterable.java:186)
at com.msx.invoicing.adjustments.database.dao.msxBillingMasterDAO.lambda$findAllByParams$0(msxBillingMasterDAO.java:37)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.withHandle(Jdbi.java:340)
at com.msx.invoicing.adjustments.database.dao.msxBillingMasterDAO.findAllByParams(msxBillingMasterDAO.java:33)
at com.msx.invoicing.adjustments.database.dao.BillingRateMappingDAO.retrieveActiveRates(BillingRateMappingDAO.java:61)
at com.msx.invoicing.adjustments.database.dao.BillingRateMappingDAOTest.testActiveRateMappings(BillingRateMappingDAOTest.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Which version of Jdbi are you using

Comment: I am using org.jdbi:jdbi3:3.0.0-beta2 for the jdbi handle

Comment: The latest release is 3.2.0. Try upgrading and see if that makes a difference. You'll want to read the release notes since 3.0.0-beta2 so you're aware of any breaking changes that might affect you. https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES

Comment: Taking a closer look at `BeanMapper` in your version, it's throwing NPE on `descriptor.getReadMethod().getGenericReturnType()`, suggesting that there is no read method. If your class doesn't have getters and setters, you want to use `FieldMapper` instead of `BeanMapper`.

Comment: @qualidafial I do not see 3.2.0 release for jdbi:jdbi3 on maven. can you quote the source where you found the release.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdbi/jdbi3